# What could be causing the `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` collection to appear empty when uploading a file through an Ocelot gateway

Tags: asp.net-core, ocelot

I have an endpoint for uploading a file that needs to be bound with my current Ocelot gateway. When I try to upload a file directly using the API, I can normally access the file through the `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` collection. However, when I use the Ocelot gateway for the same action, the `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` collection appears empty. It's worth noting that the Ocelot gateway is working perfectly with other requests - the only issue is with forwarding uploaded files. The uploaded file is small in size. Additionally, the direct endpoints of the API project work perfectly.

What could be causing the `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` collection to appear empty when uploading a file through an Ocelot gateway, despite it working perfectly when uploading directly to the API endpoint?

Comment: Maybe your issue is related with IFormFile itself(Are the two projects seprate and not sharing the same  temp floder? ),you could check this document related :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#file-upload-scenarios

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Thank you for your efforts. I have solved the problem using a delegate handler to reattach again the missed body and it works now perfectly. However, I still can't understand the reason behind especially since you have already acknowledged the healthy behavior of ocelot alone

Comment: Could you share the version used of the ocelot and .net?
I will share my solution as an answer to check

Comment: I tried with .net 5 and Ocelot 15.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a minimal example with .net 5 as below,but it works well,hopes could help,if you still have problem,please show the minimal codes could reproduce the issue

I tried with two projects in same solution: one（DemoProj） for services anotherone(OcelotProj) for Ocelot gateway:

[image]

In DemoProj,I created a controller as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
    {
       

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            var files=HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Configured as below in program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:5002");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

In Ocelot project:
I added ocelot.json:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    ........
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Default/Upload",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5002
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Upload",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

configured as below in Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x=>x.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", false, true))
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

In startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            ......
            services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
            
        }


 .......
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
 app.UseOcelot().Wait();
```

Then debug:

[image]

Result:
[image]

It seems your question doesn't have a directly relationship with Ocelot, more details  is required to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using a delegate handler, but I am still not sure about the cause of the exception whether is it an internal exception in the ocelot or things in my project affects the ocelot correct behavior !

```
public class MissingBodyInFileUploadDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

   public MissingBodyInFileUploadDelegatingHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }

   private bool IsMultipartContentType(string contentType)
   {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)
           && contentType.IndexOf("multipart/form-data", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
   }

   protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
    // https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/72cb5e6fc72699f923f22bedfce1ebd04c711985/src/Ocelot/Request/Mapper/RequestMapper.cs
    // https://github.com/osovitskiy/ocelot-sample
    var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

    if (this.IsMultipartContentType(httpContext.Request.ContentType))
    {

        
        HttpContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();


        if (httpContext.Request.Form != null && httpContext.Request.Form.Files != null)
        {
            foreach (var f in httpContext.Request.Form.Files)
            {
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await f.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(memStream.ToArray());
                    ((MultipartFormDataContent)content).Add(fileContent, f.Name, f.FileName);
                }

            }
        }
        if (httpContext.Request.Form != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in httpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
            {
                var strContent = new StringContent(httpContext.Request.Form[key]);
                ((MultipartFormDataContent)content).Add(strContent, key);
            }
        }





        request.Content = content;
    }

    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    //return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
}
```